# Elixir IEx shell, how to break out of current `receive` block

Tags: elixir, elixir-iex

I'm new to elixir, experimenting around in `iex` shell to learn, and I have be a noob question.

For simplicity let's call the current shell session process the "main process".

I spawn a child process, write a `receive` block in "main process" to listen for child message. When hit enter, it'll put the "main process" into a `waiting` status. This basically freezes the "main process", making it irresponsive to further input.

Many times I got stuck in this status by mistake. If I mess up I need to shutdown the shell and start over again, losing all the states and setups.

**My question**: is there a way to withdraw/invalidate/break out of a working `receive` block?

Or maybe is there a way that I can start another session, without killing the previous one, then send some message to it to unfreeze it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking the second approach will require a bit of work. Each `iex` instance is a separate OTP node, so in order to make those two talk to each other, you'll need to do the following:

1. specify **the same** cookie and **a different** name for each of them:

```
iex --cookie foo --name "node1@127.0.0.1"
iex --cookie foo --name "node2@127.0.0.1"
```

2. associate a global name with the receiver node (run in `node1`):

```
:global.register_name(:node1, self())
```

3. connect node1 to node2 (run in `node1`):

```
Node.connect(:"node2@127.0.0.1")
```

Now, you can start listening for messages in `node1` with `receive`. To send a message from node2 to node1, find out its PID within the cluster and dispatch the message there:

```
:global.whereis_name(:node1) |> send "Hello!"
```

Comment: I like this approach! I know that I can put a `.iex.exs` file in the cwd, but it cannot handle CLI options. Is there a way to save options in a config file?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can interrupt `receive`, you could kill the process using its PID from another process or set a `timeout` to it, then you get back the control of the session if nothing was received between this timeout window.

```
receive do
  a -> a
after
  1_000 -> "nothing after 1s"
end
```

take a look at https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/processes.html#send-and-receive

Comment: "kill the process using its PID" you mean to kill the "main procss"? That's precisely what I want to avoid.

Comment: But yeah, put in `after` kinda solve my problem, good idea. Just need to remember doing it everytime. Still hope to see other answer, if no I'll accept this one.